# call function getLabel() in joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla-extensions

After upgrading from Joomla 1.5.22 to 1.6 beta 14 I am getting this error when trying to call parameter in the xml file : Fatal error: Call to a member function getLabel() on a non-object

the code is in view.php

form->getLabel('max_chars'); ?>
                        form->getInput('max_chars'); ?>

the max_chars parameter obtained from models/setting.xml, the code is :

Am I doing wrong thing..? pls help me......

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once I commented the lines out I got an error message

> Model class compontentModelUser not found in file

I had accidentally replaced User model with a models for an JModelList instead of JModelAdmin

make sure your using the right model is all I'm saying.

It would be easier to know what the issue is with more of your code.

Hope this helps a little...